# Cannot rename files from within sandbox

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10, sandbox, windows-10-desktop

Do Win10 handle file permissions differently than Win7? Even when `Properties > Security > Advanced permissions` for files/folders seem to be identical?

**Problem:**
For several years, I've been running my browser within a Sandboxie sandbox. Now I migrated from Win7 to Win10, using the same Sandboxie configuration. But in Win10, the sandboxed applications have troubles in renaming files. Sandboxie **does work** with Win10, and no one reported the troubles I have.

**For example:** When I run Notepad in SB, it is unable to rename any files, not even those it just created. When I run Firefox from within SB, it does not remember its configuration from the previous run - that's because it is unable to rename .tmp files with updated configuration (e.g. "extensions.json.tmp" to "extensions.json"). Everything else seems to work fine.

**Q:** Do I have to set anything differently in Win10 than it was set in Win7?

**Details:** Without SB everything works correctly, in SB only the file rename seems not to work. The only difference I found is that without SB the apps are executed under my win accout, while in SB they are executed under the "ANONYMOUS LOGON" account. The privileges of both accounts seems to be almost identical (checked using the "Process Explorer" app).

The whole directories and everything within them is owned by me, and SYSTEM, Administrators and OWNER (myself) have full control on all files and folders, recursively.
When I create a folder, and then a file within that folder, I can rename that file even from within the sandbox. But I see no difference in privileges of this new folder/file and other folders/files created earlier (they all are owned by me, and SYSTEM, Administrators and OWNER have full control in all cases).

The same setup works in Win7Pro, but not in Win10Home. What's the problem?

Version: Win10Home x64 v10.0.18362, Sandboxie 5.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Sandboxie 5.30. It has been already fixed in 5.31.2.